# How to replace variable in result of Series?

Tags: series-expansion

I am trying to replace $\text{xn}$ in

$\qquad O(\epsilon )^3+\left(\text{xn}^2+2 \text{xn}\right) \epsilon +\left(-2 \text{xn}^3-4 \text{xn}^2\right) \epsilon ^2-1$

with $O(\epsilon )^2+\epsilon +1$.

I want an output like a simplified series of $\epsilon$: $-1+3 \epsilon -2 \epsilon ^2+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$.

When I evaluate

```
-1+(2 xn + xn^2) ϵ + (-4 xn^2 - 2 xn^3) ϵ^2 + O[ϵ]^3 /. xn -> 1 + ϵ + O[ϵ]^2
```

I get

[image: output]

and `Simplify` doesn't work on this output.

The solution I am using now applies `Normal` then adds the `O[ϵ]^3`.

```
temp = -1 + (2 xn + xn^2) ϵ + (-4 xn^2 - 2 xn^3) ϵ^2 + O[ϵ]^3
Normal[temp /. xn -> 1 + ϵ + O[ϵ]^2] + O[ϵ]^temp[[5]]
```

[image: output]

I'd to know is there a more efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: `temp /. xn -> 1 + \[Epsilon]` seems to give what you seek. Is that correct?

Comment: In MMA v11.0.1 `temp /. xn -> 1 + \[Epsilon] + O[\[Epsilon]]^2` does the job as expected!

Comment: my version is MMA v11.1, and temp /. xn -> 1 + \[Epsilon] + O[\[Epsilon]]^2, temp /. xn -> 1 + \[Epsilon] give the output $-1+\epsilon  \left(3+4 \epsilon +O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)\right)+\epsilon ^2 \left(-6-14 \epsilon +O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)\right)+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$ which is not i expected.

Comment: I get what you expected: see http://i.stack.imgur.com/iWoMn.png (I'm using V12.0, but the behavior of `SeriesData` has been stable through several version, I think. Perhaps try restarting your kernel) -- Site tip: Use @user to be sure a user is notified of your reply (e.g. @MichaelE2 or @UlrichNeuman); the author of a post (you in this case) is always notified of comments on the post. Also if you put code between backticks in a comment, it will be formatted properly.

Comment: Probably @UlrichNeumann copied the output and executed it. This gives me the desired output: `Block[{InterpretationBox = # &}, 
  temp /. xn -> 1 + \[Epsilon] + O[\[Epsilon]]^2 // 
   ToBoxes] // ToExpression` -- http://i.stack.imgur.com/4vVHM.png

Comment: A belated welcome to Mma.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: This might be from a buglet that will be addressed in the next release. I believe it was reported a few months ago in this forum but I cannot seem to find the right thread.

Comment: You can use  `temp /.  xn ->  1 + eps + c eps^2` then check your result is independent of c  (useful when not so obvious).